# How to make http request using desktop browser in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, selenium-webdriver

is there a good example to open up a link on Chrome on Mac os x desktop using Swift language? i found NSWorkspace example, is that the same as making an http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open in user default browser:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"), NSWorkspace.shared().open(url) {
    print("URL opened")
}
```

Comment: thanks, another follow up question, if i need to interact with the search bar displayed on google.com homepage, whats a good way to do it? i looked up at webdriver and that is not supported in swift

Comment: @AshwinBalachandran, It's another question, make another one. and accept this question if it's helped ;-)